# Master detail with sidemenu ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, master-detail

I'm trying to understand the master detail (MD) pattern in ionic with a sidemenu. The example code has 'Playlists' as master, and 'Playlist' as detail.
The states looks like this:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app.playlists', {
      url: '/playlists',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

But first off all, I don't understand why the Playlist state is called 'app.single'. I don't see the word 'single' anywhere else in the code. What if I would want to have a master detail pattern on page 1, and another different master detail pattern on page 2 (selected through the menu)? How would I call the detail state there?

And then my other question is related, I can't seem to get my own MD pattern to work. These are the codes that matter:

app.js:

```
  .state('app.master', {
    url: '/master',
    templateUrl: 'templates/master.html',
        controller: 'MasterCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.detail', {
    url: '/master/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailCtrl'
  })
```

master.html:

```
<ion-view title="Master">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item" ng-repeat="person in people">
                <a href="#/app/master/{{person.id}}">{{person.text}}</a>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

menu.html:

```
....
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/master">
          Master
        </ion-item>
....
```

The Playlists MD works all the way, but my own MD doesn't. I do get the Master list with items (controller and services work fine), but when I click an item in the list, nothing happens. Then when I swipe back (this should open the sidemenu), the detail page 'sort of' shows up without css or data. So somewhere there's a glitch. I just don't seem to understand the whole state/url thing, while I read enough documentation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are new to Ionic without any knowledge of AngularJS and Angular UI Router.

First, the dot-notation in **state** is to mark some children which will inherit from one specified parent view. As you read in the **www/js/app.js**, you will see a state **.state('app')**, and this is the parent view, **menu.html**, and the children views will be replaced in this tag, or so called Angular directive,

```
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

The children or detail views needs to specify two things,

- first, parent name, the word before the dot, as in example of sidemenu, **app.[child_name]**
- second, the child view should specify which part of parent view to be fit in, through the **views** property, as in example above,

you see this **menuContent**,

```
views: {
    'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
    }
}
```

Let's talk about Master-Detail Pattern, it is just a concept of how to display a list of items and the ability to access a single item from the list.

The **sidemenu** is an a **complicated** example for beginner.

**The simple example is to have only two pages with no tie of anything (no sidemenu, no tabs...).**

```js
 .state('cats', {
    url: '/cats',
    templateUrl: 'templates/catlist.html',
    controller: 'CatListCtrl'
  })

 .state('cat', {
   url: '/cats/:catId',
   templateUrl: 'templates/catsingle.html',
   controller: 'CatSingleCtrl'

 })
```

About **templates/catlist.html**

```js
<ion-view view-title="Cat Collection">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="cat in cats" href="#/cats/{{cat.id}}">
        {{cat.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and **templates/catsingle.html**

```js
<ion-view view-title="Cat">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>{{cat.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{cat.description}}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The point of accessing a single item from a list, is to specify the direction to the resource, in this case, the direction is via URL, **#/cats/{{cat.id}}**. So if the cat has **id = 5** then the URL will be **#/cats/5**; ok cool, let's access the single page that displays information of the cat with ID is 5. That's how you interpret it in reality.

My suggestion for learning Ionic,

- First, get to know basic AngularJS, https://angularjs.org/
- Second, get in touch with Angular UI Router navigation system, http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/
- Third, practice to create with very very small Ionic apps, make a **complicated** Hello Ionic.

Guess that my answer is what you're looking for.

> The Playlists MD works all the way, but my own MD doesn't. I do get
>   the Master list with items (controller and services work fine), but
>   when I click an item in the list, nothing happens. Then when I swipe
>   back (this should open the sidemenu), the detail page 'sort of' shows
>   up without css or data. So somewhere there's a glitch. I just don't
>   seem to understand the whole state/url thing, while I read enough
>   documentation..

I can see that you **read**, but do you ask yourself **if you know the stuff required for** it?

On front page of [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), I can see **AngularJS**, I can see **ngCordova**, I also see **SASS** (which in case, you will ask the same questions as how your custom CSS won't work and reload)...Ooops, lots of pieces to know before getting your hand in Ionic, I guess.

One thing worth to point out that if you're not coming from Angular background, you might not know about the navigation system in Ionic since the [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/) don't tell developers about Angular UI Router, you only get to know about it from the [Ionic Learn page](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/), which looks more advanced for beginners.

I know, it is hard; I was in your situation before, I felt the same way.

Anyway, have fun learning Ionic :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will definitely get more into the UI routing. Can you explain one thing in your code:  .state('cat', {...  What's the use for calling the state 'cat', since calling it 'koala' wouldn't make a difference in functionality? Where do you 'address' that state?

Comment: Btw, it works now. Appears that in DetailCtrl I was addressing the $scope, but it wasn't included in the function's parameters (or whatever those are called)

Comment: the first option in **state()** is the name, whatever you want to call it. Why? Because when you create a link, you often write `#/long/state/url`, that's not cool and you need to remember and type many. Instead, use `ui-sref=[state_name]` will resolve into a proper `href`

Answer (score 0):

@ekussberg:

My final setup included:

```
  .state('app.playlists', {
        url: '/playlists',
    templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
    })

  .state('app.playlist', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
    controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
  });
```

Notice how the playlist state is called and the url differs from yours.

Answer (score 0):

@Cake:

i have already tried like this and it works, but the transition on iOS and Web are not same smooth master-detaul as in the default way. I think it depends on the "views" element of the routing.

This code for example works, but transition not:

```js
.state('app.todo', {
  url: '/todo',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/todo-list.html',
      controller: 'TodoListCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.todo.single', {
  url: '/:todoId',
  views: {
    'menuContent@app': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/todo-single.html',
      controller: 'TodoSingleCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Well if you're concerned about the smoothness; I also ran into this issue because I get a list of 450 items (as a JSON result) in my master view. When I would navigate to a detail view (or back from detail to master), it appears rather laggy. Shortening the list solves this problem. Native iOS can handle these large lists because they re-use cells (when an item scrolls off the screen, its content is replaced for the new content).

Comment: @Cake solved the bug, my single view had a "ion-view", removed it and transition is now smooth.